# Facebook equivalent for TWTweetComposeViewController on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Does there exist something for Facebook in iOS that has equivalent functionality to the TWTweetComposeViewController? ie it's simple for the user to post a message or image to their time line just by implementing a simple modal view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS use can use `FBNativeDialog` which is available in Facebook SDK3.1. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/) `FBNativeDialog` has similar look as `TWTweetComposeViewController`

See [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-native-dialogs-ios-sdk/) from Facebook Developers documentation.

Answer (score 2):

On iOS6, you can use Social Framework like:

```
SLComposeViewController *viewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Following WWDC2012 presentation describes well about usages of the Social Framework.

[WWDC 2012 Session Videos“Integration With Facebook, Twitter and Sina Weibo](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=306)